# Not able to get this error message to work

Tags: java

The code compiles and is good up until I enter 101 and it shows up as Your grade is: . What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String args[])
   {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       int yourGrade;
       char grade = 0;

       System.out.print("Enter your grade (between 0 and 100 inclusive): ");
       yourGrade = sc.nextInt();


       if ((yourGrade>0) && (yourGrade<40))
       {
            grade='F';
        }
       else if ((yourGrade>39) && (yourGrade<55))
       {
            grade='D';
        }
       else if ((yourGrade>54) && (yourGrade<70))
       {
            grade='C';
        }
       else if ((yourGrade>69) && (yourGrade<85))
       {
            grade='B';
        }
       else if ((yourGrade>84) && (yourGrade<=100))
       {
            grade='A';
        }

       if ((yourGrade<0) && (yourGrade>100))
       { 
           System.out.println(" " + grade + " is not a valid grade.");
           System.out.println("Please enter a value between 0 and 100 inclusive.");
        }
       else
       {
            System.out.println("Your grade is:  " + grade);
        }
```

I tried adding the last bit before the final if statement yet, I still am not able to get it to display what I want it to. Please forgive me if I am doing this COMPLETELY wrong as I just started this and would like to know how to get this right.

Comment: Hint: how can a number be less than 0 *and* greater than 100?

Comment: So should it be less than or equal to? Like, I said, I'm new to this

Comment: No, you should consider the `&&` part. A single number can't be less than 0 *and* more than 100. You want to show the message if it's less than 0 *or* it's more than 100, don't you?

Comment: Thank you! I was able to figure it out in the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((yourGrade<0) && (yourGrade>100))
```

These two conditions can't *both* be true. If you want to check if one or the other is true, use *or* instead of *and*.

```
if (yourGrade<=0 || yourGrade>100)
```

Also I changed the `<0` to `<=0` since your grade conditions for an *F* don't include zero.

You also might notice that in this case, your `grade` variable will still be set to character zero, because that's how you initialised it. So printing

```
 System.out.println(" " + grade + " is not a valid grade.");
```

won't make much sense.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has helped a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Change && of last if statement to ||. Please closely look into your condition in that if statement.

Comment: Thank you so much I just figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the '&&' condition with '||', what you want the condition is (if grade is <0 **OR** grade is >100) which covers the grade 101, which would be:

if((grade<0) || (grades> 100))

{

//Conditions

}

But what you are coding is (if grade is <0 **AND** grade is >100) which is not possible as per your program's requirement.

Hope that helps !!!